# How do you farm guardian parts easily?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

How do I get giant ancient cores easily? I really need guardian parts, especially giant ancient cores to upgrade my ancient armor. I followed quite a few tutorials, but they all are either, have the guardians, but don't drop like it was in the tutorial, or there is no guardians. I tried ancient core duping, but it took forever, but it didn't yield any giant ones.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310530/how-can-i-find-ancient-cores-in-breath-of-the-wild.  Some shrines have chests that contain them - perhaps that could be a good way to supplement farming.

Comment: I already tried, but there were only like 2 or 3 shrines that have giant ancient cores, and ALL of my giant ancient cores are from treasure chests. I never got a giant ancient core from guardians. My luck is horrible.

Comment: UPDATE: I just finished Mipha's song, and there is  a giant ancient core in one of the chests in the shrine. (the one in the ocean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Hyrule Castle, if you have a good look-out and some ancient arrows they should be easy to eliminate. You'll find them at every corner. If you're not ready there's a few by the bomb shrine on the great plateau and a handful in Hyrule Field on the north side nearest to Hyrule Castle (you don't have to go close to it).

Edit: Oh! I just realized your question. The stationary guardians at Hyrule Castle (guarding that tower upward, which shoot multiple times when detecting you) have a chance they'll drop giant ancient cores. I got one once.

Comment: You can find ancient arrows at the Akkala Tech Lab (found at the NE corner of the map).

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that, but other guardians from SO far away detected me so I had to retreat inside the gatehouse (I farm lynels SO easily) I had to dodge inside and keep on firing beams from the master sword (which does only 20 damage) and finally kill it. I didn't even get a normal ancient core!                             Edit: I found out that flipping over lootable  dead guardians (near terry town) can drop ancient cores! Use a chest or lynel crusher to flip it, but only some can be moved.